# Create and populate dataframe column simulating (excel) vlookup function

Tags: python, dataframe, vlookup

I am trying to create a new column in a dataframe and polulate it with a value from another data frame column which matches a common column from both data frames columns.

```
DF1   DF2
A B   W B
———   ——— 
Y 2   X 2
N 4   F 4   
Y 5   T 5
```

I though the following could do the tick.

```
df2[‘new_col’] = df1[‘A’] if df1[‘B’] == df2[‘B’] else “Not found”
```

So result should be:

```
DF2
W B new_col
X 2 Y        -> Because DF1[‘B’] == 2 and value in same row is Y
F 4 N
T 5 Y
```

but I get the below error, I believe that is because dataframes are different sizes?

```
raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects”)
```

Can you help me understand what am I doing wrong and what is the best way to achieve what I am after?

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE 1**
Trying Corralien solution I still get the below:

```
ValueError: You are trying to merge on int64 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

This is the code I wrote

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['x', 2, 3], ['y', 5, 6], ['z', 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['One', 'b', 'Three'])
                   
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

df2.reset_index().merge(df1.reset_index(), on=['b'], how='left') \
       .drop(columns='index').rename(columns={'One': 'new_col'})
```

**UPDATE 2**
Here is the second option, but it does not seem to add columns in df2.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['x', 2, 3], ['y', 5, 6], ['z', 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['One', 'b', 'Three'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

df2 = df2.set_index('b', append=True).join(df1.set_index('b', append=True)) \
       .reset_index('b').rename(columns={'One': 'new_col'})

print(df2)


   b  a  c new_col Three
0  2  1  3     NaN   NaN
1  5  4  6     NaN   NaN
2  8  7  9     NaN   NaN
```

Why is the code above not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not clear because why is F associated with N and T with Y? Why not F with Y and T with N?

Using `merge`:

```
>>> df2.merge(df1, on='B', how='left')
   W  B  A
0  X  2  Y
1  F  4  N  # What you want
2  F  4  Y  # Another solution
3  T  4  N  # What you want
4  T  4  Y  # Another solution
```

How do you decide on the right value? With row index?

**Update**

So you need to use the index position:

```
>>> df2.reset_index().merge(df1.reset_index(), on=['index', 'B'], how='left') \
       .drop(columns='index').rename(columns={'A': 'new_col'})

   W  B new_col
0  X  2       Y
1  F  4       N
2  T  4       Y
```

> In fact you can consider the column B as an additional index of each dataframe.

Using `join`

```
>>> df2.set_index('B', append=True).join(df1.set_index('B', append=True)) \
       .reset_index('B').rename(columns={'A': 'new_col'})

   B  W new_col
0  2  X       Y
1  4  F       N
2  4  T       Y
```

Setup:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['x', 2, 3], ['y', 5, 6], ['z', 8, 9]],
                   columns=['One', 'b', 'Three'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]],
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Comment: Hi @Corralien, many thanks for asking further details.The idea is to replicate the VLookup function from excel. If a value match is found between 2 cols, pick value from another col in the same row. I’ll try to explain better.

Comment: Hi @Corralien, many thanks for pointing this out, that is an scenario that I should need to deal with too, but I’ve updated the question to remove that scenario simplify the question. For df used in my code, I’ve removed the duplicates. How can I use merge to add a new column to the dataframe?

Comment: I updated my answer according your edit. Can you check it please?

Comment: would it matter if dataframes are different sizes?

Comment: As I used `how=left` the length of output dataframe will be the length of `df2`

Comment: In fact you can consider the column B as an additional index of each dataframe.

Comment: Is it clear for you now? Is it what you expect?

Comment: sorry, I must be doing something wrong when implementing solutions, one solution crash and 2 option dont seem to create new column. Please, see update in question. Thank you.

Comment: Don't use `np.array` to create your dataframes.

Comment: I updated my post with the setup I used for the solution. Why do you use `np.array`?

Comment: the set up you used is the same than mine, but I can’t get any of the options to work. Merge give me an error and join dont seem to add new_col. What am I doing wrong? code used in the updated question, same than before. I used np.array because it was on pandas documentation example for creating data frames. Is it better dictionary?

Comment: I figured part of the issue with the join option (I was not asigning merged df to a df, so results were not being stored. Now seem to partially work, however, I still have 2 issues (see update 2 in question); 1, new_col have NaN values, 2, its also bringing col Three. Many thanks.

Comment: Sorry bad copy/paste. Try with my setup please.

Comment: The join option works, the only thing now is that is adding more columns than the desired one to df2. Any idea how to add just new column? Many thanks.

Comment: Try: `df2.set_index('b', append=True).join(df1.set_index('b', append=True)['One']).reset_index('b').rename(columns={'One': 'new_col'})`

Comment: Yeap! that does it! many thanks!!